# Is it true that if the structure damaged or corroded, the stress will be lower?

Tags: structural-analysis, stresses, abaqus

I  am comparing the stress results between original or non-corroded model to corroded model.
I found that the stress value in non corroded model is lot more bigger than the corroded model, 
is it correct?

Comment: Stress applied?

Comment: If the load stays constant and material is removed then what do you think will happen...

Comment: See https://engineering.stackexchange.com/a/22924/10902

Comment: How did you compute the stress? Maybe the stress could be lower if you only looked at the maximum local stress, since corrosion could smoothen sharp edges and reduce stress concentrations.

Comment: Without any additional information, like the materials, degree and soort of corrosion, the way it undergoes the stress, duration of experiment and the distribution of data, it is very difficult to say. I throw you a hint, if the material capable is of relaxation, then it is quite natural to predict decrease in stress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it is correct, maybe it isn't.

Suppose you "corrode away" a small radius that was causing a stress concentration, and it becomes a bigger radius. Quite likely the maximum stress in the  structure (at that concentration) will *decrease* because of the corrosion. For example an "average" stress of 1.0 and a stress concentration of 10.0 might become an "average" stress of 1.1 and a stress concentration of 9.0. Whether you count that as a "decrease from 10 to 9" or an "increase from 1.0 to 1.1" is your choice.

On the other hand if you reduce the cross section of a structural member like a beam, or the thickness of a plate, the stress will probably increase - i.e. stress = load/area, and you decreased the area.